# Invalid column name error when using QUOTENAME

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have several tables having the same structure. The tables are named by year that is 2001,2002 and so on. I am in need to search a column for a value in each table and get the count for each table.

I have created a stored procedure below but I keep getting an error

> Invalid column 'lol'

This is the stored procedure used:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CountSP]
    @TableName NVARCHAR(128),
    @SearchParam NVARCHAR(50),
    @SearchInput NVARCHAR(200)
AS 
BEGIN 
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

    SET @Sql = N'SELECT COUNT('+QUOTENAME(@SearchParam)+') FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) +'WHERE'+QUOTENAME(@SearchParam)+'LIKE '+QUOTENAME(@SearchInput)+

          + N' SELECT * FROM '+QUOTENAME(@TableName)

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql
END
```

Executing it:

```
DECLARE @return_value INT

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[CountSP]
        @TableName = N'1999',
        @SearchParam = N'USERDESC',
        @SearchInput = N'lol'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
```

Comment: Notes: Use `SysName` directly. `QUOTENAME(@TableName) +'WHERE'` will be `[TableNameYouPassed]WHERE ...` And what does `+ N' SELECT * FROM '+QUOTENAME(@TableName)` to do there?

Comment: *"I have several tables having the same structure. The tables are named by year that is 2001,2002 and so on"* **There's your problem right there.** You should have a single table with a year column to store all this information. Fixing the database structure is the solution to your problem. Any other answer is **not** a solution, it's a **workaround**. That being said I'm well aware of the fact that many times, fixing the database structure is not an option - so workarounds are needed.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Correct but not feasible here.These tables are actually database being supplied from external resource that i have migrated here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you are using `LIKE` operator there while you don't use wildcards, also use `SysName` datatype directly for object names.

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[CountSP]
(
  @TableName SysName,
  @SearchInput NVARCHAR(50),
  @SearchParam SysName
)
AS 
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT COUNT(' +
                               QUOTENAME(@SearchParam) +
                               N') FROM ' +
                               QUOTENAME(@TableName) +
                               N' WHERE ' +
                               QUOTENAME(@SearchParam) +
                               N' = ' + --You can change it to LIKE if needed
                               QUOTENAME(@SearchInput, '''') +
                               N';';
  -- There is no benifits of using LIKE operator there
  EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Then you can call it as

```
EXEC [dbo].[CountSP] N'YourTableNameHere', N'SearchInput', N'ColumnName';
```

Comment: *"I don't know why you are using LIKE operator there while you don't use wildcards"*: At a guess, because `@SearchInput` *might* have a wildcard.

Comment: @Larnu Yup, according to what I see there `@SearchInput = N'lol'`

Comment: @Sami Is there a way that instead of using the variable for table name,I pass in all the tables names found in the database? i am currently using a .net app to call the above code instead of calling it several times for each table,i want to do in one query in sql itself

Comment: @keshav That's another question somehow related, you can always click the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button, and I know you'll get a lot of good answers, not just from me :)

Answer (score 0):

This is because it is currently translated to :

```
SELECT COUNT([USERDESC]) FROM [1999] WHERE [USERDESC] LIKE [lol]
```

this means that it is comparing the "USERDESC" column with the "lol" column but from what I am understanding lol isn't a column but a value? which means you should lose the QUOTENAME for that variable.
See the documentation here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your parameter `@SearchInput` as a parameter to `sp_execute`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CountSP] @TableName sysname, --This is effectively the same datatype (as sysname is a synonym for nvarchar(128))
                                 @SearchParam sysname, --Have changed this one though
                                 @SearchInput nvarchar(200)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @Sql nvarchar(MAX);

    SET @Sql = N'SELECT COUNT(' + QUOTENAME(@SearchParam) + N') FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + N'WHERE' + QUOTENAME(@SearchParam) + N' LIKE @SearchInput;' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
    N'SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName);


    EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL, N'@SearchInput nvarchar(200)', @SearchInput;

END;
```

`QUOTENAME`, by default, will quote a value in brackets (`[]`). It does accept a second parameter which can be used to define a different character (for example `QUOTENAME(@Value,'()')` will wrap the value in parentheses). For what you want though, you want to parametrise the value, not inject (a quoted) value.

Comment: Again with the nitpicking: `sysname` and `nvarchar(128)` are different in two ways: The most important is that `sysname` might mean different length in different systems - so code written with `sysname` is more portable, and the less important is that `sysname` is not nullable.